# Problem with binding pvc with static pv in kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I'm trying to use storage account created via terraform (fileshare to be precise) and create persistent volume and persistent volume claim and use pvc for storing dag logs from Apache Airflow, however, it looks like pvc can't bind to pv as I can see the below message in the log:

```
 volume "daglogs-pv" already bound to a different claim.
```

When I check the pv, I see it has failed status:

```
❯ kubectl get pv daglogs-pv -A
NAME         CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                         STORAGECLASS    REASON   AGE
daglogs-pv   10Gi       RWX            Delete           Failed   airflow-sandbox/daglogs-pvc   azurefile-csi            47m
```

I then check the PV and it is complaining about no deletable volume plugin matched:

```
❯ kubectl describe pv daglogs-pv -n airflow-sandbox
Name:            daglogs-pv
Labels:          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:     meta.helm.sh/release-name: airflow
                 meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: airflow-sandbox
                 pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    azurefile-csi
Status:          Failed
Claim:           airflow-sandbox/daglogs-pvc
Reclaim Policy:  Delete
Access Modes:    RWX
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        10Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:         error getting deleter volume plugin for volume "daglogs-pv": no deletable volume plugin matched
Source:
    Type:              CSI (a Container Storage Interface (CSI) volume source)
    Driver:            file.csi.azure.com
    FSType:            
    VolumeHandle:      airflow-sandbox
    ReadOnly:          false
    VolumeAttributes:      resourceGroup=testrg11
                           shareName=testairflowdaglogs
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age   From                         Message
  ----     ------              ----  ----                         -------
  Warning  VolumeFailedDelete  40m   persistentvolume-controller  error getting deleter volume plugin for volume "daglogs-pv": no deletable volume plugin matched
```

Storage class:

```
❯ kubectl describe sc azurefile-csi
Name:                  azurefile-csi
IsDefaultClass:        No
Annotations:           <none>
Provisioner:           file.csi.azure.com
Parameters:            skuName=Standard_LRS
AllowVolumeExpansion:  True
MountOptions:
  mfsymlinks
  actimeo=30
ReclaimPolicy:      Delete
VolumeBindingMode:  Immediate
Events:             <none>
```

I'm lost. Was trying to resolve that but I can't. Is there a problem with the provisioner or the driver?

I was following MS guide from below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-csi-blob-storage-provision?tabs=mount-nfs%2Csecret#statically-provision-a-volume.
I'm deploying whole thing using helm and pvc/pv are created as templates. Here is the code:

pvc.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: daglogs-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: azurefile-csi
  volumeName: daglogs-pv
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

pv.yaml code

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: daglogs-pv
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: azurefile-csi
  csi:
    driver: file.csi.azure.com
    readOnly: false
    volumeHandle: {{ .Release.Namespace }} #unique-volumeid12  
    volumeAttributes:
      resourceGroup: {{ .Values.resource_group_name }}  
      shareName: testairflowdaglogs
    nodeStageSecretRef:
      name: dag-logs-storage
      namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  mountOptions:
    - dir_mode=0777
    - file_mode=0777
    - uid=0
    - gid=0
    - mfsymlinks
    - cache=strict
    - nosharesock
    - nobrl
```

and finally, secret.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  name: dag-logs-storage
data:
  azurestorageaccountname: {{ .Values.daglogscred.storageaccountname | b64enc | quote }}
  azurestorageaccountkey:  {{ .Values.daglogscred.storageaccountkey  | b64enc | quote }}
type: Opaque
```

Comment: maybe try setting `ReclaimPolicy` to `Retain`?

Comment: I was thinking about that but this does not solve the problem. I also think it should be "DELETE" as this is set in storage class and if logs are kept on storage account, pv can be safely deleted.

Comment: are you using AKS or kubernetes? which kubernetes version?

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons to occur this error while creating PVs and PVCs. Below are the few checks you can do to identify the issue.

Make sure you have created storage account with the correct SKU you have specified in Storage class. If you are using built-in storage classes provided by azure, see the details using the command `kubectl describe sc <storage-class-name>`
If you are specifying **Standard_LRS** as **skuName**, create storage account with the same configuration.
[image]

Verify the **CSI driver** used in manifest file. Use `kubectl get csidrivers` and check for the driver you are using in manifest file.
[image]

Enable the CSI drivers using the below command if not done earlier.

```
az aks update -n cluster-name -g resource-group-name --enable-disk-driver --enable-file-driver --enable-blob-driver --enable-snapshot-controller
```

Refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-storage-drivers) for more details on drivers.

Also, the link provided in post is for Azure Blob storage. Kindly follow this link [Azure Fileshare PVs and PVCs | Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-csi-files-storage-provision) as a referece to create PVs and PVCs. I am able to create PVs and PVCs by following the above checks.

[image]

[image]